# Using logical operators in an expression

Tags: python, expression

I am trying to understand that bit of code:

```py
s = list()
r = string()
# actual bit of code:
print(s and 'ERROR' or r or 'EMPTY')
```

What this does:

- if `s` is not an empty list, then you must print `'ERROR'`
- else if `r` is not an empty string you must print `r`
- else print `'EMPTY'`

I am now trying to understand why this works, and more widely how you can use logical operators in expressions, like in this example.

Comment: Focus on "using logical operators in an expression" rather than "...in a print statement" and you'll probably find more useful search results.

Comment: You should really never use code like this. `some_variable or []` would be fine, but more than one operator is too much imho.

Comment: `"abc" and "bcd"` -> `"bcd"` and `'' and "bcd"` -> `''`. `'' or "bcd"` -> `"bcd"`, `"abc" or "bcd"` -> `"abc"`. From python docs [boolean operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Comment: @luk2302 This is a very particular context: a contest where the code needed to be as small as possible. I like those because you learn the limits of python thanks to them.

Comment: Then ask e.g. on codegolf, but not on SO. And you do not learn any python limits, you primarily learn how to write unmaintainable and unreadable code. Sure, you learn some concepts too but there are easier ways of learning those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x and y` is `x` if it is "false-y" (i.e. `0`, `False`, `None`, `[]`, `''`, ...), otherwise it is `y`.
`x or y` is `x` if it is "truth-y", otherwise it is `y`.

That is, `x or y` is the same as `x if x else y`, and `x and y` the same as `x if not x else y`.

Answer (score 0):

If `s` is non-empty, `s and 'ERROR'` produces the truthy value `'ERROR'`, which short-circuited the rest of the `or` expression.

If `s` is empty, `s and 'ERROR'` produces the false value `[]`, which leads to the evaluation of `r` to determine if the value of the entire expression is `r` or `EMPTY`.

It helps to play with smaller examples using non-Boolean arguments to see how both `and` and `or` work.

```
>>> [] and "ERROR"
[]
>>> ["foo"] and "ERROR"
"ERROR"
```

It might be clearer to use the conditional expression here:

```
print("ERROR" if s else (r or "EMPTY"))
```

or just use a "naive" `if` statement.

```
if s:
    print("ERROR")
elif r:
    print(r)
else:
    print("EMPTY")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a question more focused on logical operators and [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)
.
Firstly, you need to understand that every variable has a boolean value associated with it.

An empty list is false, a list with a length of 1 or higher is true. This can be checked with the `bool()` operator:

```py
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool(['a'])
True
```

Similarly, an empty string is false and a string of one or more characters is true.

```py
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('string')
True
```

The expression `s and 'ERROR' or r or 'EMPTY'` is evaluated as follows:

1. `bool(s) and bool('ERROR')`
2. `or`
3. `bool(r)`
4. `or`
5. `bool('EMPTY')`

When any of these is True, the evaluation ends. It's merely the order of evaluation.